# How to properly use .Call in reflect package

Tags: function, go, reflection, parameters, go-reflect

Been having one last issue with my code which involves the .Call function in the reflect package.

So I'm making a call such as this:

```
params := "some map[string][]string"
in := make([]reflect.Value,0)
return_values := reflect.ValueOf(&controller_ref).MethodByName(action_name).Call(in)
```

where the method I'm making the .Call to is as follows:

```
func (c *Controller) Root(params map[string][]string) map[string] string{}
```

What I don't quite understand is how to manipulate the "in" variable in order to properly pass the map I need to into the function. I see that the second parameter in the make() is the length of the parameter? But I don't quite understand how to format the vars in order to properly pass in my parameter. I am recursively running into the error message:

```
reflect: Call with too few input arguments
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [`Value.Call documentation`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call):

> Call calls the function `v` with the input arguments in. For example, if `len(in) == 3`, `v.Call(in)` represents the Go call `v(in[0], in[1], in[2])`.

So if you want to call a function with one parameter, `in` must contain one `reflect.Value` of the 
right type, in your case `map[string][]string`.

The expression

```
in := make([]reflect.Value,0)
```

creates a slice with length 0. Passing this to `Value.Call` will result in the panic you receive as you
need 1 parameter, not zero.

The correct call would be:

```
m := map[string][]string{"foo": []string{"bar"}}

in := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(m)}

myMethod.Call(in)
```

Comment: Ah ok, ok I see, thanks so much! :) Appreciate all your help today!

Answer (score 11):

The call is trying to pass zero parameters to a controller that expects one param (`in` is an empty slice). You need to do something more like `in := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(params)}`.

You could also call `.Interface()` once you've found the method, then use type assertion to get a `func` you can call directly:

```
// get a reflect.Value for the method
methodVal := reflect.ValueOf(&controller_ref).MethodByName(action_name)
// turn that into an interface{}
methodIface := methodVal.Interface()
// turn that into a function that has the expected signature
method := methodIface.(func(map[string][]string) map[string]string)
// call the method directly
res := method(params)
```

(Then you could even *cache* `method` in a map keyed by method name, so you wouldn't have to do `reflect` operations next call. But you don't have to do that for it to work.)

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph.

Comment: Sorry. Added code. I'm saying that once you find the method, get an `interface{}` and do the rest with a type assertion.

Comment: (@nemo--does that clear up what I was saying at all? Even if you may not think it's a good idea?)

Comment: +1, now it makes sense to me :) That's not a bad idea, however you'd need to know the type at compile time which is not always possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Helps me to fixing my own problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673747/reflection-error-on-golang-too-few-arguments/27692822